# DNS - Use public domain name for internal use

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone

I've setup Bind as my intranet DNS resolving service (running on Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS).

**What I want to achieve:** 
Having a public domain name which points to a server (example: domain.com -> 1.2.3.4)
Using the same subdomain name which points to internal machines (example: machine1.domain.com -> 192.168.1.100)

**What I've done: (configuration)**

File: **/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;
    allow-recursion { 192.168.2.0/24; };
    listen-on {192.168.2.4; };
    allow-transfer { none; };

    forwarders {
            192.168.2.1; #router
            8.8.8.8; #public dns
    };

    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

    acl "truested" {
            192.168.2.0/24;
            192.168.2.4; # ns1
            192.168.2.5; # ns2
};
```

File: **/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "domain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.domain.com";
    allow-transfer { 192.168.2.5;};
};

zone 2.168.192.in-addr.arpa {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.2.168.192";
    allow-transfer { 192.168.2.5; };
};
```

File: **/etc/bind/zones/db.domain.com**

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. root.domain.com. (
                          5         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS Records
    IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
    IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.

; name servers - A Records
ns1.domain.com. IN      A       192.168.2.4
ns2.domain.com. IN      A       192.168.2.5

; 192.168.2.0/24 - A Records
server.domain.com.      IN      A       192.168.2.120
server2.domain.com.     IN      A       192.168.2.121
ns1.domain.com.         IN      A       192.168.2.4
ns2.domain.com.         IN      A       192.168.2.5
```

File: **/etc/bind/zones/db.2.168.192**

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.domain.com. root.domain.com. (
                          4         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
; name servers - NS Records
    IN      NS      ns1.domain.com.
    IN      NS      ns2.domain.com.

;       PTR Records
4       IN      PTR     ns1.domain.com.
5       IN      PTR     ns2.domain.com.
120     IN      PTR     server.domain.com.
121     IN      PTR     server2.domain.com.
```

**Problem:** When I do a DNS Lookup from a computer (having set as DNS server this server "192.168.2.4) for the IP of *domain.com* it doesn't return a value. Which consequently doesn't open the webpage of the external server (domain.com).

What do I have to change to have a DNS server working as I want?

Comment: You're looking to set up "views", where different networks get a different version of the same domain. It requires that you maintain a completely separate zone files for each version of the domain. That said, split-view authoritative is generally discouraged. In the long run it ends tends to create more operational problems than it actually solves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not setup forwarding for the zone for *domain.com* and create a new zone for a subdomain of *domain.com* for which the local name server is authoritative?

My example uses *example.com* instead of *domain.com*  ...

```
                                   192.168.33.0/24                               
+--------------------------+             |                                     
|                          |             |                                     
| Client 1                 |192.168.33.1 |             +----------------------+
| client1.corp.example.com |--------------             |                      |
|                          |             |192.168.33.5 | Corporate name server|
+--------------------------+             --------------| ns1.corp.example.com |
                                         |             |                      |
                                         |             +----------------------+
+-------------------------+              |                                     
|                         |              |                                     
|Server 1                 | 192.168.33.2 |                                     
|server1.corp.example.com |--------------|                                     
|                         |              |             +------------+          
+-------------------------+              |192.168.33.7 |            |          
                                         ---------------  Router    |          
                                         |             |            |          
                                         |             +------|-----+          
                                         |                    |                
                                                              |                
                                                              |1.2.3.4         
                                                              |                
                                                              |                

                                                         The Internet          
                                       1.2.3.5    /-----                       
                                   /--------------             |               
                +------------------                            |               
                |                 |                            | 1.2.3.6       
                | WWW server      |                            |               
                | www.example.com |               +------------|------------+  
                |                 |               |                         |  
                +-----------------+               | example.com name server |  
                                                  | ns.example.com          |  
                                                  |                         |  
                                                  +-------------------------+
```

Here are the configs:

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**:

```
zone "example.com" {
    type forward;
    forwarders {
        1.2.3.6;
    };
};

zone "corp.example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.corp.example.com";
};

zone 33.168.192.in-addr.arpa {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.192.168.33";
};
```

**/etc/bind/db.db.corp.example.com**:

```
                                       
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN corp.example.com.

@       IN      SOA     ns1.corp.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                        5;         
                        604800;
                        86400;   
                        2419200;
                        604800;
                        )

; name servers
        IN      NS      ns1.corp.example.com.

; name servers
ns1     IN      A       192.168.33.5

; hosts
client1 IN      A       192.168.33.1
server1 IN      A       192.168.33.2
ns1     IN      A       192.168.33.5
```

**/etc/bind/db.192.168.33**:

```
$TTL    604800
$ORIGIN 33.168.192.in-addr.arpa.

@       IN      SOA     ns1.corp.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                        4;
                        604800;
                        86400;
                        2419200;
                        604800;
                        )
; name servers
        IN      NS      ns1.corp.example.com.

; hosts
1       IN      PTR     client1.corp.example.com.
2       IN      PTR     server1.corp.example.com.
5       IN      PTR     ns1.corp.example.com.
```

Note: You are missing the *$ORIGIN* directive in your *db.2.168.192* zone file, but you are using shortcuts in the PTR RRs.

Nslookup test with a local installation of BIND (forwarding to *8.8.8.8* for zone *example.com* just so we can have some results):

```
> server 127.0.0.1
Default server: 127.0.0.1
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
> set type=ns
> corp.example.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

corp.example.com    nameserver = ns1.corp.example.com.
```

```
> set type=a
> server1.corp.example.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:   server1.corp.example.com
Address: 192.168.33.2
```

And for *www.example.com*:

```
> set type=a
> www.example.com
Server:     127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

Answer (score 0):

as was said you need to separate internal address space and external address space for example:

www.xyz.com on the internet 1.1.1.1 ( its an example:P)

and www.xyz.com internally is 192.168.1.20 (example)

you cannot have the same host point to 2 diffrent address and expect to get one internally and one externally unless you make "views" .

you still can connect to www.xyz.com if the ip is the public IP but then your router needs to be able to do "hair-pin" connections basically it routes the traffic to itself on its public interface . most routers are not settup to do this. you can maintain 2 dns one externally and one internally  and that has the same effect of the views.

every corporate domain has the same issue  so its been done ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually have an A record for domain.com anywhere in your config.

You want to add something like

```
   A       192.168.2.120
   A       192.168.2.121
```

as A records just below (or just above) your NS records. This will resolve "domain.com" into the two servers.

(For various reasons, while a pair of CNAMEs pointing to server1 and server2  would be a great answer, in general DNS doesn't allow this.)

You have A records for all the nameservers and hosts, but none for the domain itself.  You probably also want an MX record for the domain, too.